Uniform buffer updates and shadow-maps rendering, cause mesh twitching
Trying to render 3D shadow_maps with Vulkan, but getting buffer update de-sync I suspect.
My question is, how do I solve the problem, when rendering, and uniform buffer data updates are not in sync, so the mesh starts jumping around while getting rendered.
Can I use MemoryBarrier to solve this? I have tried, but no lucks so far.

Below is my render loop in simple terms
render_loop ->
    foreach (light: scene_lights) {

         // Render whole scene from **light_pos** view point to depth_maps
         Matrix4 light_view_matrix
         uniform_buffer.update_view(light_view_matrix);

         foreach(mesh: scene_meshes) {
            render_mesh(mesh);
         }
    }
    
    // Set uniform buffer back to using **camera_view** and render the scene again for color ..etc
    uniform_buffer.update_view(camera_view_matrix);
    
    foreach(mesh: scene_meshes) {
       render_mesh(mesh);
    }



Fixed it myself, total rookie mistake, the glitching was caused because I was only using one uniform buffer for multiple frames in flight. Once I switched to using multiple uniform buffers, it got fixed.

If you show your code for switching between the multiple buffers, that could be a big help to future readers struggling with similar issues.
